# How do you make a multi lined text document within a batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file

What I mean is this:

Echo testing >>  new_text_document.txt

Is there a way to give "testing" multiple lines?

Might it work better with variables like:

Set xyz= testing
Echo %testing% >> new_text_document.txt

I don't know.  If you can help,  it would be apreaciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply add more `echo`  commands

Comment: What are you aiming to have?  A text file with many lines of the same text?  Or maybe a text file containing random text on several lines - say numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, it really depends on what you need. One way is to put newline in a variable (note the 2 empty lines are critical):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set NL=^


echo two!NL!lines >> new_text_document.txt
```

Use one or two > does not matter. since >> appends you can do many lines of echo too

```
@echo off
:other stuff
echo multiple  >> new_text_document.txt
echo lines  >> new_text_document.txt
echo.  >> new_text_document.txt
echo of text  >> new_text_document.txt
```

that may be clunky so you could do something like this instead

```
@echo off
:other stuff
(
  echo multiple 
  echo lines 
  echo.  
  echo of text  
) >> new_text_document.txt
```

Last but not least you can do something similar to the bash trick but you will have no EOL marker.

```
@echo off
more +4 %~f0 >> new_text_document.txt
exit /b

your 
multi
line 
text
```

In addition to this its possible to for loop the file yourself this way you can have a EOL marker for many different pieces.